# bootstrap datepicker is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

i included all the css and js filesin my date.html file.but still i didnt get the datepicker.i dont know what is the problem.can anyone help me  out.

here my html code.

date.html

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>date  /title>
     <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="bootstrap/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        Date
        <input type="text"  id="datepicker" />
    </div>
        <script src="bootstrap/jquery.19.1.min.js">
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                    });  
                       });

       </script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> 
      <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: get rid of duplicates and fix loading order of scripts

Comment: The second link to stylesheet is a script file not a stylesheet.

Comment: @user3117036 i corrected but still i didnt get..

Comment: @charlietfl that also i corrected still i didnt get.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 versions of jQuery.js loading and 2 versions of bootstrap.js and you have a script tag nested in another script tag which doesn't work

Try this configuration:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                });  
                   });

   </script>
```

You probably don't need the `bootstrap-datepicker.js` either as it is probably included in `bootstrap.js`.

Nest step is to use browser console (F12) to look for errors and files not being loaded

Comment: need to do some basic javascript debugging then. Without more details is hard to help. See my last note in answer